# Homomorphic image of matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Is that true that any homomorphic image of $M_n(R)$ ($R$ a ring with 1) is of the form $M_n(\overline{R})$, where $\overline{R}$ is an homomorphic image of $R$?

It's clear for me that if $\overline{R}$ is an homomorphic image of $R$, then $M_n(\overline{R})$ is an homomorphic image of $M_n(R)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the ideals of $M_n(R)$?

Comment: Of the form $M_n(U)$, where U is an ideal of R. But I don’t see how this help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideals of $M_n(R)$ are all of the form $M_n(I)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$. Now the obvious map
$$
M_n(R)\to M_n(R/I)
$$
is a surjective ring homomorphism. What's its kernel?

---

The kernel is obviously $M_n(I)$. In particular, every ring of the form $M_n(R/I)$ is a homomorphic image of $M_n(R)$.

Conversely, if $\alpha\colon M_n(R)\to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, then $S\cong M_n(R)/\ker\alpha$. On the other hand, $\ker\alpha=M_n(I)$ for a unique ideal $I$ of $R$. Therefore $S\cong M_n(R)/M_n(I)\cong M_n(R/I)$.

Comment: This is an area of mathematics that I’ve never sufficiently penetrated. What kind of ideal must $I$ be? Right? Left? Two-sided?

Comment: @egreg, its kernel is $M_n(I)$. Sorry but I still do not see how this shows that every homomorphic image of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(\overline R)$, where $\overline R$ is an image of R.

Comment: @P.G there are a couple solutions on the site classifying two-sided ideals of matrix rings this way. Just search

Comment: @Lubin Two sided. It clearly doesn’t work for on sides ideals (just consider the case of $R$ a field.)  There is a description for those too, but it’s not as simple.

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then $M_n(R)/M_n(I) \cong M_n(R/I)$. In particular $M_n(I)$ is an ideal of $M_n(R)$. My question is: if $M_n(R) \to J$ is an  epimorphism, then $J = M_n(\overline R)$, where $\overline R$ is an image of R?

Comment: @P.G I added the details